# Как правильно уничтожать вложенные объекты JSON-документа в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-xe5

```
var
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
...

JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S) as TJSONObject;
try
  JSONArray :=  JSONObject.Get(0).JsonValue as TJSONArray;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add(JSONArray.Get(0).ToString);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(JSONArray); // если это закомментировать то работает но JSONArray остается в памяти.
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(JSONObject);  // а если нет, то тут вылетает Invalid pointer operation
end;
```

После уничтожения `JSONObject`, можно обратиться к `JSONArray` (в случае если мы его ранее не уничтожили принудительно) объект будет существовать, но структуры и данных самого JSON-документа в нем уже не будет. Тоже самое с `JSONObject`, если сначала уничтожить `JSONArray`  Как в таком случае правильно их уничтожать и освобождать память?

Вот пример JSON-документа:

```
{"asks":
    [["0.01129999",0.9997237],["0.01130000",594.26412711],["0.01130826",0.23004724],["0.01130999",0.25231793]],
 "bids":
    [["0.01129800",174.30861783],["0.01128867",0.13287659],["0.01128817",0.0097447],["0.01127559",241.94881004]],
 "isFrozen":"0","seq":254407265
}
```

Comment: Дополните свой код, что значит ".. то работает но JSONArray остается в памяти" ? *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.*

Comment: Уничтожать надо только `JSONObject`. Какую структуру вы пытаетесь распарсить?

Comment: Имеется в виду, если исключить из кода строчку с удалением массива - `FreeAndNil(JSONArray)` то ошибка Invalid pointer operation при уничтожении `JSONObject` возникать не будет, НО после этого уничтожения можно обратиться к `JSONArray`, например так: `Memo1.Lines.Add(JSONArray.ClassParent.ClassName);` Из чего я делаю вывод, что объект остается.

Comment: Не надо обращаться к `JSONArray` после уничтожения `JSONObject`.

Comment: Да мне в общем-то нет никакой необходимости к нему обращаться, я к тому что на самом деле `JSONArray` не уничтожается при уничтожении `JSONObject`, как мне написали выше.

Comment: `JSONArray` - не объект, а ссылка на данные. И после уничтожения `JSONObject` ссылка становится невалидной. Тут нету утечки памяти, просто такая логика использования парсера.

Comment: Хм, происходит от класса, декларируется как объект, имеет конструктор диструктор, и прочие св-ва объекта, но при этом не объект? Что значит становится невалидной ссылкой, если через нее можно запросить некоторые параметры объекта и успешно получить результат? То о чем я писал ранее -`JSONArray.ClassParent`

Comment: Да, но для вас это не объект, который нужно уничтожать, а ссылка для доступа к данным. См. мой ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627341/177722.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться параметром `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`, (Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://mirsovetov.net/show-memory-leek.html)) который покажет есть утечки памяти или нет и какие объекты не уничтожены. По идее после уничтожения JSONObject'a  все должно очистится. Даже возможен вариант что у Вас остается "мусорная" ссылка на объект которого уже нет.

Comment: Это отличный совет, но к сожалению, это комментарий, а не ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный парсер json устроен таким образом, что во время парсинга, при вызове метода `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue`, он **создаёт иерархию объектов** на каждое json поле и возвращает корневой объект, через который можно получить доступ к любому полю.

Создаваемые объекты наследуются от класса `TJSONAncestor` и имеют свойство `FOwned`, которое устанавливаются в `True` (в том числе и для корневого объекта).

При уничтожении корневого объекта, он проверяет, находятся ли у него во владении дочерние объекты и если такие имеются, уничтожает их:

```
destructor TJSONObject.Destroy;
var
  Member: TJSONAncestor;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if FMembers <> nil then
  begin
    for i := 0 to FMembers.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Member := TJSONAncestor(FMembers[I]);
      if Member.GetOwned then
        Member.Free;
    end;
    FreeAndNil(FMembers);
  end;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Аналогично и дочерние объекты, при уничтожении, уничтожают свои вложенные объекты, если таковые имеются.

Таким образом, пользователю достаточно вызвать один деструктор корневого объекта, чтобы освободились все созданные объекты.

Обратите внимание, что в строке:

```
JSONArray :=  JSONObject.Get(0).JsonValue as TJSONArray;
```

**не происходит создания объекта**, вы лишь запрашиваете у корневого объекта ссылку на объект, который **был создан во время парсинга json-а**. Вы можете пользоваться ей до тех пор, пока не уничтожен корневой объект. И, соответственно, ни в коем случае нельзя пытаться удалять руками этот запрошенный объект.